# How to install green wall on wall with metal grate?

Tags: construction

I am looking to install a green wall system onto this wall, which has a metal grate along the top. I know I will have to reinforce the wall before I install the wall, to support the weight, what would be the best way to do this? Wooden batons?

Thank you
Katherine [image]

Comment: What Green Wall, like plants ?

Comment: You would really need to have someone onsite be able to make an assessment. We can't tell from here what the wall's made of, how much weight will be added, whether the building structure below this wall would support the additional weight. Wood, however, is probably not the correct answer as it will rapidly decay with plants growing on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to tell what the structure of your existing wall is and whether it can support the weight of your greenwall or not.

I would look to support the greenwall through posts straight down to the concrete walkway and just use the existing wall to hold the greenwall upright. Again, this depends on the structure of the existing wall and how much wind you get there, etc.- really hard to say from here.